# Given a binary alphabet {0,1}, write a regular expression that recognises all words that have an even number of ’1’s and starts and ends with a ’0’

Tags: compiler-construction, regular-language

I'm working through some exam questions for a module in college. I've been asked to create a regular expression that recognises all words that have an even number of ’1’s and starts and ends with a ’0’ when given a binary alphabet {0, 1}. However, the solutions are not available online and I want to verify that my solution is correct as I then must convert create an NFA -> DFA using Subset Closure from this regular expresion.

I'm wondering if the following is correct?

`0*, (1, 0*, 1)*, 0*`

Comment: Should your expression match `0000` ? IOW are you considering no 1's a valid match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually  I think you solution has some flaws.

1. It's not checking whether your word starts or ends with `0` (should be `+` instead of `*`
2. It does not work, e.g. for `0110110`, since the `0` in the middle can not be matched (include possibility to match only `0`)
3. It checks whether there is an occurance of the searched string in your word and not whether the whole word matches the string (include `^` and `$`)

My suggestion is to use the following RegEx: `^0+((10*1)|0*)*0+$`

Comment: If my answer did help you, it would be great if you could accept is and, if possible and no other answers are needed, close your question.

Comment: OK I'll do that now, thanks again.